# Updating the Same Landing Page Functionality from Form Results

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I currently want to update the same page on my wordpress website with results that a user submits.

For example, if a user fills out a form on one page, it would update another page. The current plugins that we are using is Contact Form 7, Post My CF7 Form. How would we achieve this functionality and if we need short code, where would we put that?